# Display nice algebraic (like LaTeX) expressions on a PyQt table GUI

Tags: python, pyqt, latex, pyqt5

I want to display TeX-like expressions on a pyqt table widget. All the answers I came up with tell that I need to create a new widget to show those expressions correctly, but I want to know if it's possible to include them inside a cell of a table widget on pyqt5.

Here's a picture of what I want to accomplish:

[image: case]

So basically i want to display `self.General_Table.item(0, 0).setText('m^2')` as a TeX-like expression.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the relevance of the screenshot? It appears to show normal ascii text, which doesn't require any special formatting.

Comment: I know, but i would like that m^2 to display as a TeX-like expression instead of just "m^2", if that's possible. The screenshot was to illustrate what i wanted to change.

Comment: Why not just use unicode, like this: `m²`?

Comment: I didn't knew i could just set the text to `m²`! It works now. Thanks!

Comment: PS: for other mathematical unicode characters, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_operators_and_symbols_in_Unicode) and [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_subscripts_and_superscripts).